# Ios equivalent of android tabbed lists

Tags: android, ios, list, tabs

Is there a way to create tabs in iOS similar to those on Android. That is, moving between them with swipes and as though they are panes beside one another?

Mike

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried anything yet?  If you have, add it to your question.  4 space indent puts stuff int a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled=YES`.

See the [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code in the Apple Documentation that demonstrates it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SwiftUI you can try `TabView`(is a kind of `UIPageViewController`) with `tabViewStyle(.page)`

```
TabView {
    Text("A")
    Text("B")
    Text("C")
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
```